# How to convert .m4a audio files to .mp3 use command line?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, codecs, audio-recording, m4a

How to convert .m4a audio files to .mp3 command line? (with no deterioration in quality, if possible). Ubuntu 16.04LTS
media info:

```
General
Complete name                            : show.m4a
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Apple audio with iTunes info
Codec ID                                 : M4A  (M4A /mp42/isom)
File size                                : 55.5 MiB
Duration                                 : 1h 48mn
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 71.7 Kbps

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : HE-AAC / LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 1h 48mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 72.0 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 93.8 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz / 22.05 KHz
Frame rate                               : 21.533 fps (1024 spf)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 54.9 MiB (99%)
Writing library                          : Nero AAC codec 1.5.4.0
Encoding settings                        : -q 0.25
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I note that your input file is actually a Variable Bitrate (VBR) AAC file with an *overall* bitrate of 71.7 Kbps and a *maximum* bitrate of 93.8 Kbps. So you actually have two reasonable choices: encode to a Variable Bitrate MP3 file or simply decide on a suitable bitrate for Constant Bitrate (CBR) MP3 encoding. And FFmpeg is certainly the best tool for both of these!

**1. Variable Bitrate (VBR) Encoding**

This would be my own choice if only for the reason that the original AAC file is also a VBR file. Encoding to MP3 with a variable bitrate of 70-105 Kbps can be mapped to FFmpeg with the `-q:a 8` option as below:

```
ffmpeg -i show.m4a -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 8 output.mp3
```

And I suspect that this is your *best* option with your input file.

**2. Constant Bitrate (CBR) Encoding**

Constant Bitrate (CBR) Encoding is a little over-used IMHO but if this suits your playback equipment best then it is a valid choice. Since your input file has an *overall* bitrate of 71.7 Kbps and a *maximum* bitrate of 93.8 Kbps we could perhaps fudge the numbers a little and use the following:

```
ffmpeg -i show.m4a -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 96k output.mp3
```

Some experimentation might be in order with good choices for the bitrate being taken from the following LAME 'allowable' standards: 64k, 80k, 96k, 112k. Whatever sounds best on *your* playback hardware...

**References:**

- [FFmpeg MP3 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3): FFmpeg Trac's great guide to encoding to mp3. Especially note the VBR mapping table marked 'LAME Bitrate Overview'.

Answer (score 7):

Give this a try:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

This will install the `ffmpeg` package.

We can see what formats are acceptable by typing:

```
ffmpeg -formats
```

Or

```
 ffmpeg -codecs
```

Navigate to the directory your audio files are in with the `cd` command. If you need help finding the directory use the `ls` command.

```
$ ls
backup.log         Desktop    examples.desktop  Music     snap
branches-tutorial  Documents  flick             Pictures  Templates
SumDocument        Downloads  mozilla.pdf       Public    Videos
```

Lets say my files are in the `Desktop` folder. I would then type:

```
cd Desktop
```

Now I will be in the correct directory.
Following, now we type:

```
ffmpeg -i show.m4a newFileName.mp3
```

To convert with a specified bitrate ( In your case it looks like 71.1Kbps with a max of 93.8Kbps - I'm not sure what will happen if trying to use the max vs the Overall bit rate, unfortunately), we run:

```
ffmpeg -i show.m4a -b:a 71100 newFileName.mp3
```

I pulled this information from https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ffmpeg-audio-conversion/

Please note that conversion to a lossless codec (mp3) inevitably will lead to (not necessarily audible) quality loss.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [**FFmpeg**](https://www.ffmpeg.org) command-line version.

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.m4a -acodec libmp3lame -ab 93k outputfile.mp3
```

In the process of converting it to MP3, always there will be some quality loss(Although it may be unnoticeable to human hearing). MP3 is a lossy format (no matter the format of the original). You can read more about lossy and lossless formats [here](https://samplerateconverter.com/educational/best-audio-file-format)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the same advice as the constant bitrate of 96k sampling (as explained above) but as a single BASH command line:

```
for i in *.m4a; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 96k  "${i%.*}.mp3"; done
```

This will automatically scan the present directory and converting files from .m4a into mp3 with that constant bitrate.